# Simple spring animation for game that does not stretch

Tags: animation, drivers, unreal-engine

#### I wanted to create spring animation for my model's legs in unreal engine 5.

First I tried to scale bones, and use contraints to match the height. It worked but spring was deformed, it lost circular shape and become more oval. So I am looking for other technique that could help me.

*Spring stretched*

[image: Bone Stretching]

##### Drivers / Shape keys

I tried drivers, but they don't work when exporting FBX.

I tried shape keys and it is the same, no effect.

My understanding is that fbx can not store deformations and animation comes only from bones changes right?

*Spring not animated in unreal engine*

[image: Spring not affetcted in unreal engine]

Other formats are kinda weird, I would like to stick to FBX

I know I could try some spiral of bones, but it feels too much and not necessary for top-down rts game. I am open for suggestions or some performance debate.

Comment: FBX supports bone and shapekeys. What went wrong with shapekeys?

Comment: @L0Lock oh you are right, but problem is that I have to reanimate spring to match legs position in unreal, I don't like idea of keying each  positon,  I am gonna see if there is some way to drive "morph target". I see some tuts, but I must see if it works as I want :D

Comment: Well yes you can do that. You could drive the shapekey value per the angle formed by by the shin and thigh bones. Or have an aditional bone you can move manually and drive the shapekey from its position.